# Format Specifer with Assert in C++

Tags: c++, assert, format-specifiers

Is here anyway to use Format specifier with assert in C++.

Like we use `assert('Hello %s'%'World')` in python.

Similarly, we have any function in C++.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [`boost::format`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) will look familiar to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no format specifiers for `assert()` in C++.

Besides, `assert()` does not take a string as input to begin with, only a scalar value that is compared to 0 (unless you are thinking of `static_assert`, which can take an optional error message that is reported if the condition fails).

Python's `assert()` throws an `AssertionError` exception. In C++, you can throw a `std::exception` (or derivative) object, which you can construct with a string message formatted however you want (using `sprintf()`, `std::ostringstream`, `boost::format`, etc).